# Dealing with overflow of a navigation bar

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a website main navigation bar (ideally using only css). I am having trouble dealing with the overflow of links at smaller screen resolutions.

I'm wondering if someone could provide some suggestions for a better way to handle the menu at smaller screen resolutions.

The natural behaviour of the links is to start on a new line so I tried increasing the height of the bar at a smaller media query.

```
nav, ul, li, a {
    padding: 0 0;
    margin: 0 0
}

nav.navibar {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #283035;
    height: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

nav.navibar .active{
    background-color: #E74310; 
}

ul.navilink{
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom: 0;  
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
}

ul.navilink li{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

ul.navilink a{
    display:block;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    color:#ffffff !important;
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: Raleway, Helvetica, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    /*min-width: 150px;*/
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

ul.navilink a:hover{
    background-color: #000;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/*--- DROPDOWN ---*/
ul.navilink ul,
ul.navilink li:hover ul li ul{
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    display: none; 
}
ul.navilink ul li{
    padding-top: 0px; 
    float:none;
}

ul.navilink ul a{
    white-space:nowrap; 
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: left;
}

ul.navilink li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2147483647;
}

ul.navilink li ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left:100%; 
    z-index: 2147483647;
}

ul.navilink li:hover a{
    background:#000 !important;
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul.navilink li:hover ul a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul.navilink li:hover ul li a:hover{
    background:#f05221 !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    nav.navibar {
        height: 120px;
        /*overflow: auto;*/
    }
}


<nav class="navibar">
<ul class="navilink">
    <li><a class="active" href="logout">Logout</a></li>
    <li><a>General</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="po_search">PO Search</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Inventory</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="grazing_rep">Grazing Report</a></li>
            <li><a>PI Checks</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="batch_rotat">Batch Rotation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="dynamic_pi">Dynamic PI Variance</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pi_query_ch">Queries Check</a></li>
                    <li><a href="wrong_check">Wrong Item Checks</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>QC Inbound</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="qc_error_ch">QC Error Checks</a></li>
                    <li><a href="qc_process">QC Process</a></li>
                    <li><a href="qc_putaway">QC Putaway</a></li>
                    <li><a href="qc_inbound">QC Stats</a></li>
                    <li><a href="qc_targeted">QC Targeted</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: cud you plz create JSFiddle?

Comment: Hi, I have created one here, https://jsfiddle.net/0ga9twxp/1/

Comment: A common practice is to hide the menu on smaller screens and show a burger icon to toggle it from some side or the top. Another idea is to replace the text with icons on smaller devices but you'll need clear and descriptive icons for that to be intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of BOTH the height:60px AND the @media query height:120px.

The nav div will then automatically be just as tall as it needs for however many rows of links need to wrap at any given moment.